# Stata: Rolling Window Estimations, while interval in dates are uneven

Tags: date, time-series, stata, intervals, rolling-computation

I seek to calculate the running sum of a variable (AR) over 58 time periods, being t(+3):t(+60). These rolling windows are calculated for each `nid`. If from a certain date point no additional sixty observations are present, I want the rolling sum of t(+3) until the last available observations with respect to the *nid* variable.

I have tried the following:

```
format date %td
isid nid date
tsset nid date
ssc install rangestat
rangestat (sum) AR, interval(date 3 60) by (nid)
```

Although Stata does as I asked, the outcome of each running sum is incorrect (as it does not equal the sum of AR(t+3):AR(t+60), t being the number of observations). After reading the guides, I reckon this has something to do with my *date*, as the intervals between dates in my observations are highly uneven. This might be 1 day, as well as an interval of 4 days in the next *date* observation. I think setting the delta in my time series to 1 per observation rather than 1 day would solve this, yet do not know how to.

My data looks like the following:

```
nid       year anndats_act     ret                   vwretd                AR  CAR DOW   (CAR_t3_t60 CAR_tm1_t1) long nid 
"00030710" 2014 19998                     .            .0007672172             . . 4    .4537178350437898  -.0010001262417063117 1    .4537178350437898
"00030710" 2014 19999   .008108087815344334             .009108214  -.0010001262 . 5    .5161017065693159  -.0010001262417063117 1    .5161017065693159
"00030710" 2014 20002    .03163539618253708             -.00158689    .033222288 . 1   .48926858956110664    .048222048208117485 1   .48926858956110664
"00030710" 2014 20003                     0   -.014999760000000001     .01499976 . 2    .4617805665184278       .026614960283041 1    .4617805665184278
"00030710" 2014 20004  -.005717287305742502               .0158898    -.02160709 . 3   .46142884949222207    .020880695432424545 1   .46142884949222207
"00030710" 2014 20005   .006272913888096809             -.02121511    .027488023 . 4    .4485122445039451    .006232652143808082 1    .4485122445039451
"00030710" 2014 20006  -.012987012974917889             -.01333873    .000351717 . 5    .4922841447405517    .027839740068884566 1    .4922841447405517
"00030710" 2014 20009                     0              -.0155178      .0155178 . 1    .4025316827464849    -.03419169504195452 1    .4025316827464849
"00030710" 2014 20010   -.04736839979887009             .002341094     -.0497095 . 2    .4079152133781463     .04379293601959944 1
```

I am using Stata 16.0 on Mac.

Comment: For your data, with at most one observation per daily date, `rangestat` is willing to sum 58 values if present within your specify window but will sum only as many non-missing values as are present, even down to 0 if none exist. So, the problem is just that you want something else that `rangestat` neither offers nor provides directly, andthe fault is in your time variable.. You want a time metric that excludes weekends and holidays, and `bysort   nid (anndats_act): generate t = _n` should get you closer.

Comment: A warm thank you once more Mr. Cox. The single line solved the problem - rangestat interval (t low high) now returns the proper values of the summations I need.